# PHPhotos and Core Data. What NSManaged object type to use for PHObject?

Tags: ios, core-data, photosframework

I am trying to use Swift to build an app that uses the new PHPhotos API and Core Data. What I want to do is either capture or select a photo from the library. Save it to a Custom Album AND to my Core Data database.

I have both working individually, but I am saving the image to the db which seems redundant using NSData as the data type. Leaving me the same image twice, one in the Album, and one in the DB. What I want to do is save a reference to the image to the DB then retrieve it using that reference.

Then use Change Observer to handle the updates or changes from my Album to the DB and vice versa.

Right now, I am not certain what data type to use for the PHObject because I get errors using NSData for the image data.

Here is my Class that I'm using in Core Data.

import Foundation
import CoreData

class MyEntry: NSManagedObject {

```
@NSManaged var date: NSDate
@NSManaged var image: NSData
@NSManaged var make: String
@NSManaged var model: String
@NSManaged var name: String
@NSManaged var entries: NSOrderedSet
```

}

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You may store PHObject property localIdentifier to safely access a Photos Framework asset. It is a NSString.
2. You can always retrieve the asset back using the method

   fetchAssetsWithLocalIdentifiers:(NSArray *)identifiers options:(PHFetchOptions *)options

Apologies for the objective C code. I am not that familiar with Swift. Hope this helps you.